# how can i post a message facebook wall from my application

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

Is there any detailed explanation from begining to end that how i can integrate facebook sdk to my application. 
I just want to send text body to facebook wall with my application.
I use story board and my app have three views. I will use my third views content for sending. Please help me i confused there are a lot of explanation but each of them about something different. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

I used Facebook SDK 3.0 for integrating my app with Facebook.

You can get the SDK from https://developers.facebook.com/ios/. The SDK has already included a couple of examples. You can build them to see how they work.